# DllCall() - I keep getting ErrorLevel '-4'

Tags: autohotkey

I am learning how to make DLL calls in AHK V1 and I have covered some distance and understand a great deal, mostly thanks to this excellent article [DllCall and structs tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=63708) by jeeswg but I am at a stumbling block I cant seem to get past.

I am using the code found [HERE](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/69464-how-to-determine-a-window-is-in-which-monitor/) by user shinywong, as a starting point, its just another peace of code that impressed me and I am merely using it as a reverse engineering exercise:

```
windowHandle    := WinExist("ahk_exe firefox.exe")
;monitorHandle  := DllCall("monitorfromwindow", "uint", windowHandle, "uint", 0x2)              ;Returns the same error, "-4"
monitorHandle   := DllCall("user32.dll\monitorfromwindow", "uint", windowHandle, "uint", 0x2)
```

After calling the DLL, When I check the `ErrorLevel` its set to `-4`, which according to the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/DllCall.htm#error) means:

> -4: The specified function could not be found inside the DLL.

and of course, `monitorHandle` is empty, I don't know where to begin diagnosing such as an issue,  but I ruled out the possibility of it being my PC through [Nirsoft's DllExp](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) tool, it concurs that there definitely is a function called `monitorfromwindow` inside the `user32.dll` file.

What I am expecting is a successful call of this DLL function so I can be on my way with reverse engineering/understanding shinywong's code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you already got your answer on Reddit:

u/GroggyOtter posted the following solution:

*Seems to work and errorlevel stays at 0*

```
#Requires AutoHotkey 1.1+ 
#SingleInstance Force 
#Warn
Return

*F1::
    ff_hwnd := WinExist("ahk_exe firefox.exe")
    If !ff_hwnd {
        MsgBox, FireFox not found.
        Return
    }
    mon_hwnd := MonitorFromWindow(ff_hwnd)
    MsgBox, % "FireFox handle: " ff_hwnd
            . "`nMonitor handle: " mon_hwnd
Return

MonitorFromWindow(hwnd) {
    return DllCall("user32.dll\MonitorFromWindow"
                ,"Ptr" ,hwnd
                ,"Int" ,0x2)
}
```

*Further u/GroggyOtter offered:*

The documentation tells you what it returns:

Return value
If the window intersects one or more display monitor rectangles, the return value is an HMONITOR handle to the display monitor that has the largest area of intersection with the window.

If the window does not intersect a display monitor, the return value depends on the value of dwFlags.

It tells you it's going to return a handle to the monitor.
A handle is never a string. It's an address that points to something in memory.

You can read more about monitors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/about-multiple-display-monitors) and a link to [HMONITOR and Device Context.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/hmonitor-and-the-device-context)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very usefull. I appreciate the links too. I will go through them too!